# Assign HTML input form to a model conditionally

Tags: asp.net-core, model

I am designing a web application with multiple forms where all go through the same inserting procedure with table names being the only difference.
What I am doing now is to have separate controllers (and services) for each.
As over simplified example:

```cs
//Data is sent to this action via a HTML form
public async Task<IActionResult> Insert_FirstModel(MyFirstFormModel model)
{
    _firstService.Insert(model);

   //Return
}
```

What I am trying to do is to include a form ID inside the sent data from client so I can bring all my insert operation to a single controller.
This would need determining the sent form model according to the ID like below:
(This example does not work of course and is just for demonstration)

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Insert(int FormID)
{

    switch(FormID)
    {
       Case 1:
           MyFirstFormModel model = new MyFirstFormModel();
           model = ReceivedFormData;
           _firstService.Insert(model);
       Case 2:
           ...    
    }
   //Return
}
```

**Question:** Is is possible to bind received form data to model according to conditions in the controller?

Comment: Is the model passed from the different forms same ?

Comment: No, each form has its own model, so right now I have different action for each but I am trying to merge them somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Request.Form["FiledName"]` to bind received form data to model.

Here is a working example:

Studio model and Address model

```
public class Studio
{
    public int StudioID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Forms in CreateAddress view and CreateStudios view

```
@model MVCDemo2_2.Models.Studioes.Studio

<h1>CreateStudios</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Insert">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input hidden name="FormID" value="1"/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}

@model MVCDemo2_2.Models.Studioes.Address

<h1>CreateAddress</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Insert">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input hidden name="FormID" value="2" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Street" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Street" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Street" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

A general method in controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Insert(int FormID  )
    {
        switch(FormID)
        {
            case 1:
                Studios studio = new Studios();
                studio.Name = Request.Form["Name"];
                _context.Add(studio);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                break;
            case 2:
                Addresses address = new Addresses();
                address.Street = Request.Form["Street"];
                _context.Add(address);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                break;

            case 3:
               ...
        }
        //Return
    }
```

**Edit :**

For multiple inputs in the form , You could cutomize a `DynamicModelBinder` class like below:

```
public class DynamicModelBinder:IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        var result = new object { };
        var form = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;
        var formId =Convert.ToInt16(form["FormID"]);
        if (form == null)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("FormData", "The data is null");
        }
        var innerType = LookupType(formId);

        var modelMetadataProvider = bindingContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IModelMetadataProvider>();

        if (innerType != null)
        {
            var mvcContext = bindingContext;
            //required service
            var _mvcOptions = mvcContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value;
            var parameterBinder = mvcContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ParameterBinder>();
            var _modelBinderFactory = mvcContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IModelBinderFactory>();
            var _modelMetadataProvider = mvcContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IModelMetadataProvider>();

            //var finalModel = Activator.CreateInstance(innerType);
            var modelMetadata = _modelMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(innerType);
            var modelBinder = _modelBinderFactory.CreateBinder(new ModelBinderFactoryContext
            {
                Metadata = modelMetadata,
                CacheToken = modelMetadata
            });
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = modelMetadata;
            await modelBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.Model);
        }


        //bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
    }
    private static BinderItem[] GetParameterBindingInfo(
    IModelBinderFactory modelBinderFactory,
    IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider,
    ControllerActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
    MvcOptions mvcOptions)
    {
        var parameters = actionDescriptor.Parameters;
        if (parameters.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var parameterBindingInfo = new BinderItem[parameters.Count];
        for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
        {
            var parameter = parameters[i];

            ModelMetadata metadata;
            if (mvcOptions.AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes &&
                modelMetadataProvider is ModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProviderBase &&
                parameter is ControllerParameterDescriptor controllerParameterDescriptor)
            {
                // The default model metadata provider derives from ModelMetadataProvider
                // and can therefore supply information about attributes applied to parameters.
                metadata = modelMetadataProviderBase.GetMetadataForParameter(controllerParameterDescriptor.ParameterInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                // For backward compatibility, if there's a custom model metadata provider that
                // only implements the older IModelMetadataProvider interface, access the more
                // limited metadata information it supplies. In this scenario, validation attributes
                // are not supported on parameters.
                metadata = modelMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(parameter.ParameterType);
            }

            var binder = modelBinderFactory.CreateBinder(new ModelBinderFactoryContext
            {
                BindingInfo = parameter.BindingInfo,
                Metadata = metadata,
                CacheToken = parameter,
            });

            parameterBindingInfo[i] = new BinderItem(binder, metadata);
        }

        return parameterBindingInfo;
    }
    private struct BinderItem
    {
        public BinderItem(IModelBinder modelBinder, ModelMetadata modelMetadata)
        {
            ModelBinder = modelBinder;
            ModelMetadata = modelMetadata;
        }

        public IModelBinder ModelBinder { get; }

        public ModelMetadata ModelMetadata { get; }
    }
    private Type LookupType(int formId)
    {
        switch (formId)
        {
            case 1:
                return typeof(Studio);

            case 2:
                return typeof(Address);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Use the custom binder in action :

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Insert( int FormID,[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof( DynamicModelBinder))] object model)
    { 
      // the stuff you want
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, only working example I have came across online so far. Is it also possible not to assign all properties of model manually. Some of my forms have more that 30 inputs.

Comment: @farshad , please check my code updated. Hope this can help you.